# Problem when using rarfile in Python: BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data: req=65536 got=0

Tags: python, rar

This problem happened to me when using the library rarfile in Python, particularly with the method `extractall()`:

**BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data: req=65536 got=0**

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS:

```
brew install carlocab/personal/unrar
```

> Credit to [iliatimofeev](https://github.com/iliatimofeev)@GitHub, [markokr/rarfile: issues#68](https://github.com/markokr/rarfile/issues/68#issuecomment-1139945654)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This solution I found in [ProgrammerAH](https://programmerah.com/error-when-python-rarfile-decompresses-rar-file-badrarfile-38153/), and I adapted it to Linux. Install the necessary libraries:

- pip install rarfile
- pip install unrar
- sudo apt install unrar (I did this step to guarantee that it works)

Enjoy!!!